# How long has a TLD to be at least

Tags: php, dns, filter-var

A customer of mine complains that with `filter_var()` and the option `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` an e-mail address like:

```
john.doe@example.c
```

gets accepted. So my question now is: How long has a TLD to be at least? I mean we know `.com`, `.org`, `.us`. But TLDs like `.g` or `.a` don't exist as far as I know.

The further questions are:

- Could they even exist?
- Do they exist in real world (WWW) already?
- How likely is it that "one char" TLDs will exist in the WWW one day?

Comment: `foo@bar` is also a valid address! It may not resolve if I sent to it from where I am, but it may well resolve inside some intranet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something else: Check if the domain can been resolved and if it has an MX record. If not the domain cannot recieve emails and you can reject that email address.

Check also the [`getmxrr()`](http://php.net/getmxrr) function and don't forget the umlautdomains also known as idn or punycode domains use for that the [`idn_to_ascii()`](http://php.net/idn-to-ascii). Here is a simple example script:

```
$parts = explode('@', $email);
if(!getmxrr(idn_to_ascii($parts[1]))) {
    echo 'Reject email address';
}
```

Comment: This is the most specific and cleanest solution to this all. Thx for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid implementing an algorithm that might not reflect all the valid domain names you could use the [checkdnsrr](http://php.net/checkdnsrr) function on the domain name.

Something like:

```
$parts = explode('@', $email);
$domain = $parts[1];
if (!checkdnsrr($domain)) {
    echo 'Invalid domain';
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I'll build a method `validateEmail($email, $checkDns = true) {}` so that I can turn of the DNS check if I'll ever have to do so.

Comment: Note that this depends on the availability of your DNS resolvers, i.e. this may suddenly, temporarily reject emails if something's wrong with the DNS servers or teh intarwebs are too busy. Still the best solution though.

Answer (score 2):

An TLD for now has at least 2 letters.

You can see this in a list of all the TLD's available.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

**The solution provided by mishu is a great solution so you should use that!**